# IMCE browse server image upload button not displaying on ckeditor toolbar

Tags: 7, users, files

I just installed and enabled IMCE for drupal 7 and assigned the IMCE icon in the *full html* input format page, but the icon is not appearing in the ckeditor toolbar. I even set the permissions for the IMCE.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have it fully functioning yet, but I am getting closer...

EDITOR APPEARANCE

- Make sure you Load the sample toolbar more accurate to what you will use when you drag the button up there.
- **Plugins** = check the box "*Plugin for inserting files from IMCE without image dialog*"

Once I added the plugins, it started working.

Now it isn't complete, because I get an error when I click on (an existing image's) "Image Properties" and "Browse Server" that says the requested page (ckfinder.thml?....) could not be found. So I am still working on it but at least it is partially working.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you scroll down that same page and look for **file browser settings** and make sure its set to IMCE. Mine was on none and after switching that, the file browser upload button showed up in the image dialog popup.

[image]

Comment: Just to add: CKEditor comes in as an iframe, and browsers aggressively cache iframe content iirc, so make sure to empty your browser cache everytime you test.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, there's no "IMCE" button on CKEditor. The "Browse Server" button however should now appear when you press "Insert/Edit Image" or "Insert/Edit Link" buttons, if you enabled IMCE in WYSWIWYG settings.